# pubsub triggered cloud function not ack the message, even after func executes successfully

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have this simple python function where i am just taking the input from pubsub topic and then print it.

```
import base64,json

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data'])
    data           = json.loads(pubsub_message)
    for i in data:
         for k,v in i.items():
              print(k,v)
```

If i had used the pubsub_v1 library, there i could do following.

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

def callback(message):
        message.ack()

subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
```

How do i ack the message in pubsub triggered function?

Comment: How many subscription do you have on your topic? How can you say that the message isn't acked?

Comment: i have one subscription on this topic.
i can still pull the messages from the queue even after function successfully exits.
"Function execution took 3346 ms, finished with status: 'ok'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your latest message, I understood the (common) mistake. With Pubsub, you have

- a topic, and the publishers can publish messages in it
- (push or pull) subscriptions. All the messages published in the topic are duplicated in each subscription. The message queue belong to each subscription.

Now, if you look closely to your subscriptions on your topic, you will have at least 2.

- The pull subscription that you have created.
- A push subscription created automatically when you deployed your Cloud Function on the topic.

The messages of the push subscription is correctly processed and acknowledge. However those of pull subscription aren't, because the Cloud Function don't consume and acknowledge them; the subscription are independent.

So, your Cloud Function code is correct!

Comment: yes yes yes, that was the case, i totally missed this part. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Anyways to ack or let the pubsub know to deliver again from a cloud function? If i throw an error, the function instance totally shuts down giving a cold start again.

Comment: In http triggered, HTTP return code not in (102,200,201,202,204) stands for NACK. The instance isn't shut down and you won't have cold start for the next message (or for the new presentation of the same one). However, if the function crash/terminate the instance (unhandled exception, or simply and `exit` in the code), yes the instance needs to restart (so, cold start)

Answer (score 1):

The message should be ack'd automatically if the function terminates normally without an error.

Comment: but thats not happening, even after function successfully exits, i can still pull the message from the queue.
"Function execution took 3346 ms, finished with status: 'ok'"

Comment: If you have a specific scenario where things do not work the way you expect, you should ask a question outlining the steps anyone can take to reproduce and observe what's wrong.